# Resave NSUserDefaults value for selected key for index.row

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have array `NSUserDefaults` type :

```
    let userValue = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "lastName": self.lastNameLbl.text ?? "", "city": cityLbl.text ?? ""] as! [String : String]
    var userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []
    UserDefaults.standard.set(userArray, forKey: "userInfo")


  And save this array in first `ViewController`
```

In second `ViewController`  Im display this array in `UITAbleView`

```
 class ...

 var userInfo = [[String:String]]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 userInfo = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell

 var userItem = userInfo[indexPath.row]
 cell.nameLbl?.text = item["name"]
 cell.lastNameLbl.text = item["lastName"]
 cell.cityLbl.text = item["city"]
```

and under `UITAbleView` I have 3 `UIextField's` and `UIButton` for the opportunity to change user information

When user pass text in `UIextField's` I want to resave value for key

How can I remove selected name and save new name to correctly user??

To Abhirajsinh Thakore answer :

Im update code in cellForRowAt

```
var userItem = userInfo[indexPath.row]
 cell.nameLbl?.text = item["name"]
 cell.lastNameLbl.text = item["lastName"]
 cell.cityLbl.text = item["city"]

item["name"] = cell.nameLbl?.text


  var maArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

  item.updateValue(cell.nameLbl?.text, forKey: "name")
        maArray.append(item)
```

But its not save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch your complete array from `Userdefaults`

Now do is that get the new values from `textField` and replace that at the specific `indexPath.row`

For e.g:

```
var userInfo = [[String:String]]()

 let data  = userInfo[indexPath.row]
 data["name"] = txtName.text
 data["address"] = txtAddress.text
```

And now store this full array back to `userDefaults` and you will get the updated Result every Time.

Hope this helps.

### Edit with reference to the code

Do like this:

```
var maArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

    let innerData = maArray[indexPath.row]

    innerData["name"] = cell.nameLbl?.text
    innerData["lastName"] = cell.lastNameLbl.text
    innerData["city"] = cell.cityLbl.text


    // And save the maArray back to userDefaults
```

Comment: Im update code and add this to question but this not work

Comment: Buddy you are doing wrong. I mean why you are appending. Just replace the value.

Comment: Edited the answer for you. @Nazar

Comment: @ Abhirajsinh Thakore ,    Fatal error: Index out of range .  in      `let innerData = maArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Can you print the maArray and lemme know whats the output of it.? So that i can make a proper code for you.